# Overflow hidden when pressing page before in Safari

Tags: html, css, scroll, safari, overflow

I really can't find the answer anywhere.

My website's results page works well, except when I go on the details page of a product, then come back to results by using page before button, the overflow becomes hidden, I cannot scroll anymore. When I refresh, everything works well again. I've tried all overflow-y values on the body and it didn't help. It only happens on Safari (I'm using Safari 9.0.3). Is there a way in Javascript or something else to restart the scrolling process?

Thank you, if you need more details I will provide them.
Benjamin

Here is a line included in the head : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

HTML

```
<div class="results">
search results shown here inside foo
<div class="foo">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.results {
margin-top: -100px;
padding-top: 100px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: -80px;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
margin-left: 200px;
}
.foo {
position: static;
height: 205px;
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yes we need to see some code

Answer (score 0):

Any code ?
Also, you can first try to empty your cache.

Are you sure it really hides overflow ? Try to see in the web inspector or in Firebug if Safari overwrites some of your properties.